# Переместить разделы Windows вперед диска

Tags: ubuntu, gparted, разметка-диска

Всем привет, поставил Windows 10 рядом с Linux Ubuntu и теперь в Gparted такая картина. /dev/sda8 - это C:\ раздел с Windows. Я хочу переместить sda7 и sda8 на места, занятые sda4 и sda5. Короче, чтобы sda4, sda5 и sda6 были в самом конце диска. Как я могу такое сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну, если оно не драг-энд-дропается - то тогда только через копирование разделов через clonezilla\acronis в образ на другой винт, убивание оригинального раздела тут перемещение нужного, создание пустого такого же и разворачивание из бэкапа.

Comment: @don Rumata, да, я сохранил нужные файлы в винде, снёс линукс, переместил диск C в начало, создал разделы под линукс в конце диска и поставил линукс снова

Comment: Ну т.е. типа помогло?

Comment: @don Rumata, да, красота теперь)

Comment: Ну тогда как ответ оформлю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если оно не драг-энд-дропается - то тогда:

1. Копирование разделов через clonezilla\acronis в образ на другой винт.
2. Убивание оригинального раздела тут.
3. Перемещение нужного.
4. Создание пустого такого же.
5. Разворачивание из бэкапа старого.

Comment: спасибо большое!